# RethinkDB not starting in cloud9

Tags: npm, rethinkdb

I have a Cloud9 space and I have a small app running. Currently I am trying to start the Rethink service and its not working. I installed rethink using

```
npm install rethink -g --save
```

and I then type

```
rethink
```

to try and start the server, and it tells me

```
bash: rethink: command not found
```

what am I doing wrong? It seems pretty straight forward yet its not.

Answer (score 1):

Not everything can be installed via npm, as its name suggests (Node Package Manager), it's mainly for Node.js packages and programs. RethinkDB is primarily written in C++, and its tooling is written in Python.

The rethink NPM package is an ODM (Object Document Mapper, similar to an ORM) one of the few Node.js packages which allow your Node.js program to interface with the database. Refer to it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rethink

To install RethinkDB on Cloud9, follow the instructions for installing RethinkDB on Ubuntu here: https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install/ubuntu/. You only need to follow the section that says "With binaries".